# Where to place data attribute of a python request in scrapy Request

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests

I have a python request containing **data** and I have to replace it with a scrapy request but I'm not able to find a way, where to place this data in scrapy request

```
data = '{"username":"xyz@gmail.com","password":"123"}'

response = requests.post('https://my.matterport.com/api/v2/user/login/', data=data)
```

Where do I place data in scrapy request

```
Request('https://my.matterport.com/api/v2/user/login/', callback=self.foo)
```

or In scrapy FormRequest

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for [this part of the documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login).

Have you tried

```
FormRequest('https://my.matterport.com/api/v2/user/login/', 
            formdata=data, callback=self.foo)
```

?

Comment: Ok I just noticed your `data` is a string, it should be a dictionary. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to perform this request. One way is to use **Request** of **scrapy.spiders** and other way is to use **FormRequest**. In case of simple Request you just need to mention the method of request which will be POST in your case however FormRequest is by default set to POST.

In case of using Scrapy Request:

```
form scrapy.spiders import Request
data = {"username":"xyz@gmail.com","password":"123"}
Request('https://my.matterport.com/api/v2/user/login/', method='POST', callback=self.foo, body=json.dumps(data))
```

In case of using FormRequest:

```
data = {"username":"xyz@gmail.com","password":"123"}
FormRequest('https://my.matterport.com/api/v2/user/login/',  formdata=data, callback=self.foo)
```

Comment: The first way, using a JSON body, will not work for the question. Only the second way will work.

Answer (score -1):

```
 request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com",
                           cookies=[{'name': 'currency',
                                    'value': 'USD',
                                    'domain': 'example.com',
                                    'path': '/currency'}])
```

or try like this (class is not obliged)

```
import scrapy

def authentication_failed(response):
    # TODO: Check the contents of the response and return True if it failed
    # or False if it succeeded.
    pass

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    if authentication_failed(response):
        self.logger.error("Login failed")
        return
```

show this link may be it will help you, https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html